# Azure DefaultCredentials with IntelliJ not working because no AuthMethodDetails.json is written

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-identity

I am trying to use [Default Azure credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/identity-azure-hosted-auth#default-azure-credential) to connect to a Service Bus Queue from my Spring Boot application (Kotlin) and have trouble getting the setup to work locally with the IntelliJ plugin.

I am trying to connect to a Service Bus queue to send a message, if I use a connection string it works fine but I would like to handle access with the default credentials.

```
val predictionRequestsClient = ServiceBusClientBuilder()
    .credential(topicModelingProperties.namespace, credential)
    .sender()
    .queueName(topicModelingProperties.predictionQueue.requests)
    .buildClient()
```

I've tried using the IntellijCredentials directly:

```
val credential = IntelliJCredentialBuilder()
    .keePassDatabasePath("<MY PATH TO PWD STORAGE>")
    .build()
```

or the default credentials (long term goal):

```
val credential = DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder()
    .intelliJKeePassDatabasePath("<MY PATH TO PWD STORAGE>")
    .build()
```

I did install the [Azure Toolkit plugin in IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8053-azure-toolkit-for-intellij), logged in in my IDE, the plugin tells me even so in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Tools > Azure config in Intellij]

Nevertheless when I try to send something to the queue I get the following error using the IntelliJCredentials:

```
[2022-06-28 08:47:13.285] ERROR [task-4] --- o.s.a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler: Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void at.teamecho.topic.CommentClassifier.addToClassificationQueue(at.teamecho.comment.CommentSubmissionEvent)
com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusException: IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
    at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.mapError(ServiceBusSenderAsyncClient.java:820)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3733)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:415)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
    at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onError(FluxTimeout.java:219)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:132)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onError(MonoIgnoreThen.java:278)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenCoordinator.signalError(MonoWhen.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoWhen$WhenInner.onError(MonoWhen.java:288)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxMapFuseable.java:140)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:192)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:172)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:903)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onError(FluxMap.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onError(Operators.java:2063)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoEmpty.subscribe(MonoEmpty.java:46)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpChannelProcessor$ChannelSubscriber.onNext(AmqpChannelProcessor.java:398)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpChannelProcessor.lambda$onNext$0(AmqpChannelProcessor.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque.forEach(ConcurrentLinkedDeque.java:1650)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.AmqpChannelProcessor.onNext(AmqpChannelProcessor.java:112)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRepeatPredicate$RepeatPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxRepeatPredicate.java:86)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:210)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:127)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:236)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:146)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onComplete(SerializedSubscriber.java:146)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTimeout.java:234)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:83)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:118)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:856)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:944)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$ReplaySubscriber.onNext(FluxReplay.java:1323)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDistinctUntilChanged$DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxDistinctUntilChanged.java:149)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDistinctUntilChanged$DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.onNext(FluxDistinctUntilChanged.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replayNormal(FluxReplay.java:856)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxReplay$SizeBoundReplayBuffer.replay(FluxReplay.java:944)
    at reactor.core.publisher.ReplayProcessor.tryEmitNext(ReplayProcessor.java:508)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.Handler.onNext(Handler.java:89)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.handler.SessionHandler.onSessionRemoteOpen(SessionHandler.java:87)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.BaseHandler.handle(BaseHandler.java:146)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.engine.impl.EventImpl.dispatch(EventImpl.java:108)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.dispatch(ReactorImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.qpid.proton.reactor.impl.ReactorImpl.process(ReactorImpl.java:291)
    at com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.ReactorExecutor.run(ReactorExecutor.java:91)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:139)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1731)
        at com.azure.messaging.servicebus.ServiceBusSenderClient.sendMessage(ServiceBusSenderClient.java:178)
        at at.teamecho.topic.CommentClassifier.addToClassificationQueue(CommentClassificationService.kt:41)
        at at.teamecho.topic.CommentClassifier$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8be0e530.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.authenticateWithIntelliJ(IdentityClient.java:358)
    at com.azure.identity.IntelliJCredential.lambda$getToken$2(IntelliJCredential.java:87)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
[2022-06-28 08:47:13.328]  INFO [reactor-executor-5] --- c.a.c.a.i.h.SendLinkHandler: {"az.sdk.message":"onLinkRemoteOpen","connectionId":"MF_4ff63d_1656398832884","linkName":"cbs:sender","entityPath":"$cbs","remoteTarget":"Target{address='$cbs', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, capabilities=null}"}
[2022-06-28 08:47:13.328]  INFO [reactor-executor-5] --- c.a.c.a.i.AmqpChannelProcessor: {"az.sdk.message":"Channel is now active.","connectionId":"MF_4ff63d_1656398832884","entityPath":"$cbs"}
[2022-06-28 08:47:13.328]  INFO [reactor-executor-5] --- c.a.c.a.i.h.ReceiveLinkHandler: {"az.sdk.message":"onLinkRemoteOpen","connectionId":"MF_4ff63d_1656398832884","entityPath":"$cbs","linkName":"cbs:receiver","remoteSource":"Source{address='$cbs', durable=NONE, expiryPolicy=SESSION_END, timeout=0, dynamic=false, dynamicNodeProperties=null, distributionMode=null, filter=null, defaultOutcome=null, outcomes=null, capabilities=null}"}
```

Which basically tells me **IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE**, but in the IDE I am logged in.

After googling and debugging a bit it seems I am missing the `AuthMethodDetails.json` file, that should be written by the plugin - it does not exist on my machine.

I have tried to log in with OAuth 2.0 and the Device Login already but none of the options were writing the AuthMethodDetails / making the connection work.

[image]

#### TLDR;

Do I need the AuthMethodDetails.json for the Intellij plugin to work?
What could be a reason for it not being written for me and how can I get it written?

#### Versions:

- com.azure:azure-identity:1.5.2
- com.azure:azure-messaging-servicebus:7.9.1
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) - Build #IU-221.5921.22, built on June 21, 2022

Comment: Does either of these solutions work? [azure-identity - authenticateWithIntelliJ fails to load credentials](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/17499#issuecomment-736818679) and [IntelliJ token credential not working with IntelliJ version 2021.1.2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/22429)

Comment: Another similar issue: [Authenticating to Azure with DefaultAzureCredential and IntelliJ Authentication not available](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/27307) which is being tracked here [IntelliJCredential not working with Azure Toolkit for IntelliJ](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/21150)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Unfortunately those issues do not help - I don't get any errors on JSON parsing, the whole file just does not exist for me, also not in the hidden folder (.AzureToolsForIntelliJ)

The windows file search tells me that the file AuthMethodDetails.json is nowhere to be found at all.

Comment: It's strange that `AuthMethodDetails` is not found/generated because it's part of `azure-identity`. References: [DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. IntelliJCredential authentication failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68050074/defaultazurecredential-authentication-failed-intellijcredential-authentication) and [Client library for Microsoft Azure Identity](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.azure/azure-identity/1.3.0-beta.2/source-code/com/azure/identity/implementation/IdentityClient.java)

Comment: [IntelliJAuthMethodDetails.java](https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-for-java/test-coverage/azure-identity/com.azure.identity.implementation/IntelliJAuthMethodDetails.java.html)

Comment: I've tried to manually create the file but I don't know the content for the four properties so I switched to use Azure CLI for now but I would prefer to use the plugin. 
I'll wait a few more days and then open a Github issue - thanks so far.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm on IntelliJ 2023.1 and I also don't have that file created.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I switched to using the Azure CLI